# Limit Touchevent to one time

Tags: android, touch, motion

how can I limit the Touchevent to one/ two time(s), that means the user can only do one time a touchevent.

Here is the code from the Touchevent, I dont know how I should edit it, that the touchevent only react one or two times.

```
   @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float currentX = event.getX();
    float currentY = event.getY();
    float deltaX, deltaY;
    float scalingFactor = 15.0f / ((box.xMax > box.yMax) ? box.yMax : box.xMax);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    deltaX = currentX - previousX; //vorherig(previous)  - aktuell
          deltaY = currentY - previousY;
          ball.speedX += deltaX * scalingFactor;
          ball.speedY += deltaY * scalingFactor;
      break;              
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // Modify rotational angles according to movement

    }
    // Save current x, y
    previousX = currentX;
    previousY = currentY;
    return true;  // Event handled
 }
```

Comment: So you want that the code inside the onTouchEvent is run only once?

Comment: You can disable the `View` when user touches it by using `View.setEnabled(false)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain an `boolean` variable as below...

```
boolean touchCounter = false;

@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float currentX = event.getX();
    float currentY = event.getY();
    float deltaX, deltaY;
    float scalingFactor = 15.0f / ((box.xMax > box.yMax) ? box.yMax : box.xMax);

    if (touchCounter == false) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

             touchCounter = true;

             deltaX = currentX - previousX; //vorherig(previous)  - aktuell
             deltaY = currentY - previousY;
             ball.speedX += deltaX * scalingFactor;
             ball.speedY += deltaY * scalingFactor;
             break;              
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

             touchCounter = true;

             // Modify rotational angles according to movement
             break;

        }
    }

    // Save current x, y
    previousX = currentX;
    previousY = currentY;
    return true;  // Event handled
 }
```

Comment: How can you increment `boolean`? I mean what do you mean by `touchCounter++` where `touchCounter` is a `boolean`?

Comment: thank you very much hamid it run well! :)                                         and what should I change, when the user have 2 touchevents and not only one?

Comment: then you should maintain it using a `int` type counter variable...and apply condition based on that counter...if counter<2 then it should allow to continue touchevent or not.

Comment: I change boolean to int, wrote if (touchCounter <2) and change all true and false to 2, but the touchcounter in action_up to 1. where is my mistake?

Comment: you look like you know much in android, how can I stop the ball, I think the ball must stop in action_up, but I dont know how I should write it, I try ball.speedx-- and ballspeedy--. And the ball should stop from the devices not from the user. :)